# Unable to surf web with Thinkpad

Tags: windows-7, networking, thinkpad

We've got a new Thinkpad here, running Windows 7.  Having problems with the networking/Access Manager.  When using the wireless profile, everything works fine.  However, when using the wired profile, we're unable to use web browsers.  Everything else works fine, we're able to connect fine with anything that doesn't use port 80 or 443 (for example, DNS, traceroute, ping, SMB, and even surfing to websites on port 81 works!).

Machine was originally setup with the Windows built-in utility rather than Access Manager.  Have tried resetting everything, but still have the same results.

Any ideas (other than reformat and start fresh)?

Update: Port 80 and 443 work fine over IPv6, this appears to be an IPv4 specific problem.

Comment: End user decided that just having wireless was fine.  Won't be able to research this any further.  :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I do have another update after all.  Problem has nothing to do with the actual computer itself.  For whatever reason, our Cisco ASA refuses to do PAT for our wireless segment.  So, when available NAT addresses run out, rather than flipping additional devices onto PAT, it's just dropping the IPv4 packets (obviously, IPv6 doesn't suffer the same fate, since NAT/PAT are not necessary for IPv6 in our configuration) for those devices!

Answer (score 3):

Theres a setting in ThinkVantage Access Connections where if you choose a wireless profile, it'll disable wired connection.

Before reformatting, just try clearing Window's wifi profiles and sticking to Access Connections. Also disable the option that disables simulatenous wireless and wired connections. There are also profile specific firewall and etc options.